# How to match this string in Regex pattern?

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I have a string where this string phonenumber={9 digits or 0 digits, just this two options} is repeated multiple times, what I want to do is get a regex pattern to match this string and replace it for an empty string.

I tried this but it didn't work, I don't know if the problem is the pattern or the way I'm trying to replace all of "phonenumber={9 digits}" from the base string:

```
var result =baseString.toString().lowercase().replace(Regex("\\\\bphonenumber=\\\\b\\d{9}"),"")
```

Comment: And with triple quotes `"""\bphonenumber=\d{9}\b""".toRegex()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are these issues with that regex:

- The regex will see `\\b` instead of `\b`, so in the string literal you need to add only one level of escaping: `"\\b"`. Alternatively, use the raw string literal (with `"""` delimiters), and then there is no escaping.
- The second `\b` occurs at a spot where it is not needed, since it sits between `=` and a digit. You'll want this `\b` to be put *after* the digits pattern.
- There is no provision to match when there are 0 digits. For this you can make the 9 digits optional with a `?`

So:

```
Regex("""\bphonenumber=(?:\d{9}\b)?""")
```